# R ggplot unresponsive dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I need particular values to change with selection.

```
#server.R 
bio <- read.csv('bio.csv')


bioSlice <- subset(bio, "Athlete" == "AA" & "Biomarker" == "B1")
h<-bio[,1]
i<-bio[,2]

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 formulaText <- reactive({
  paste(input$Athlete, "~", input$Biomarker)
 })

 output$caption <- renderText({
   formulaText()
 })

output$bioPlot <- renderPlot({
d=data.frame(x1=c(1, h),x2=c(h, i))
print(ggplot() +
})

})

#ui.R
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
   headerPanel("Results"),



  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("Athlete", "Athlete:",
                list("1" = "1",  
                     "2" = "2")),

    selectInput("Biomarker", "Biomarker:",
                list("B1" = "B1",
                     "B2" = "B2"))
  ),

  mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("caption")),
    plotOutput("bioPlot")

  )
))
```

My data.frame doesn't seem to like the way I've set the variables. Maybe I need to get it to start automatically at say h=bio[1,1], i=bio[1,2], etc. But how do I set this while making the code responsive to the users input?

I don't want to give away too much of my code, but if anyone has any ideas as to how to make the values react to the input, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the plot to be *reactive* as you intend, you have to make the `subsetting` part to be reactive. It has to take the user input values (Athlete and Biomarker in your case) and use those values to subset the data before you plot it. Notice that your `d=data.frame(...)` statement is not reactive at all.

In your server.R, you have to add a reactive function:

```
  biomarkerSlice <- reactive({
    subset(biomarker.df, Athlete==input$Athlete & Biomarker==input$Biomarker)
  })
```

and call this reactive function using `biomarkerSlice()` when plotting. That way, the resulting plot will change with user input.

Your UI.R is fine. (I just added a `tableOutput` line to illustrate.) All the reactive elements above go into Server.R.

Here's a fully working version that I tested with some data dummy data.

#### UI.R

```
    #ui.R
    # Define UI for Blood Results application
    shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

     headerPanel("Results"),


  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("Athlete", "Athlete:",
                list("AA" = "AA",  
                     "BB" = "BB",
                     "CC" = "CC",
                     "DD" = "DD",
                     "EE" = "EE")),

    selectInput("Biomarker", "Bio marker:",
                list("Creatinine" = "Creatinine",
                     "B2" = "B2",
                     "B3" = "B3",
                     "B4" = "B4"))
  ),

  mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("caption")),
    tableOutput("biomarkerDataTable"),
    plotOutput("biomarkerPlot")

  )
))
```

#### Server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# dummy data
biomarker.df <- data.frame(Athlete=rep(c("AA","BB","CC","DD","EE"), 4),
                           Biomarker=rep(c("Creatinine","B2","B3","B4"), 5),
                           Outside = sample(50:70,20, replace=T),
                           Lower = sample(40:80,20, replace=T),
                           Value = sample(42:90,20, replace=T),
                           Higher = sample(60:110,20, replace=T))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  biomarkerSlice <- reactive({
    subset(biomarker.df, Athlete==input$Athlete & Biomarker==input$Biomarker)
  })

  # Compute the formula text in a reactive expression since it is 
  # shared by the output$caption and output$Plot expressions
  formulaText <- reactive({
    paste(input$Athlete, "~", input$Biomarker)
  })

  # Return the formula text for printing as a caption
  output$caption <- renderText({
    formulaText()
  })

  #subset to the Ath and the BioMarker of interest
  output$biomarkerDataTable <- renderTable({
    biomarkerSlice()
  })

  # Generate a plot of the requested Athlete against requested Biomarker
  output$biomarkerPlot <- renderPlot({
    melted_df <- melt(biomarkerSlice())
    print(ggplot(melted_df, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=variable))+
            geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
            theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(vjust=0.5, size=20))
          )
  })

})
```

And that produces a reactive plot as you desire (Shown below). As you change the inputs, the plot changes.
[image]
Hope that helps you move forward.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I'm still having an issue with my code. I think the problem is with
     h<-biomarker[,1]
     i<-biomarker[,2]
     j<-biomarker[,3]
     k<-biomarker[,4]
     l<-biomarker[,5]
     m<-biomarker[,6]
     n<-biomarker[,7]
I need these values to change when the user selects something. These variables change my plot. However, when they are outside the server code, they don't change, and I get the error "x must be of length 1 or 2", and when they are inside of it, I receive the error that h,i,j,k,l,m,n are undefined. I wonder if you have any pointers? Thanks again.

Comment: Looks like you want to conditionally display certain columns of your dataframe depending on the biomarker selected. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: When the user makes their selection of, say for example, AA vs B2, I need the varables to go to that specific place in the dataset. So if that selection was made - the values would go to row 6. So h<-biomarker[6,1], i<-biomarker[6,2], etc. Is this possible?

Comment: I have updated the code so that as the selection changes, the values to different rows. Try this server.R and ui.R, and you will see it working.

Comment: Thanks again Ram, this is great. I'm still having a small issue though. The subsetting is exactly what I need, but is there a way I can say h <-biomarkerSlice[,1] outside of the server part of the code and still have it react to the reactive subset biomarkerSlice, if you get me? I tried this and received the error "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable".

Comment: Outside of the server code, you can do static subsetting, but not reactive ones.

Comment: Just as I did for the biomarkerSlice, make h(), i(), j() etc. to be reactive functions, inside the Server block. Then, pass the relevant biomarkerSlice to those reactives, and the values of h,i etc will change depending on the input selections.